# Grep - Remove rows from a txt if it contains numbers

Tags: file, grep

I have a txt file, and I would like to remove all the lines if it contains numbers (and/or '@' characters).

Can you please help me how to do it?

Thank you!

Rob

Example:

a.txt contains:

```
12@11gsd
12ss
@dfsdf
ahaha
```

output:

```
ahaha
```

Comment: Read the grep documentation with particular attention to character classes and the "-v" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -v [0-9@] file
ahaha
```